# Laravel - store the value of primary key from persons table in the foreign key of users table

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, primary-key, eloquent

I'm using the framework Laravel.

I have 2 tables (Users and Persons). I want to store the primary key person_id of the persons table in the foreign key person_id of the users table. At the moment I use this  **$user->person_id = '1'**;

Table Users

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `festival_aid`.`users` (
  `user_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_password` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `user_salt` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `user_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_modified` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_deleted` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_lastlogin` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_locked` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_token` VARCHAR(128) NULL,
  `user_confirmed` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `person_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_email_UNIQUE` (`user_email` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_users_persons1_idx` (`person_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_persons1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`)
    REFERENCES `festival_aid`.`persons` (`person_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table Persons

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `festival_aid`.`persons` (
  `person_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `person_surname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `person_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `person_modified` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `person_deleted` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The index action

```
public function index()
    {
       $person = Person::with('user')->orderBy('person_id')->paginate(10);

       return View::make('persons.index')
           ->with('person', $person);
    }
```

The store action

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();


    $rules = array();
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if($validator->passes())
    {

        $password = $input['user_password'];
        $password = Hash::make($password);

        $person = new Person();

        $user = new User();

        $person->person_firstname = $input['person_firstname'];
        $person->person_surname = $input['person_surname'];

        $user->user_username = $input['user_username'];
        $user->user_email = $input['user_email'];
        $user->user_password = $password;

        $person->save();

        $user->person()->associate($person, 'person_id', 'user_id');

        $user->save();

        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created user!');
        return Redirect::to('persons/index');
    }
    else {
        return Redirect::to('persons/create')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

User migration

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
        $table->increments('user_id');
            $table->string('user_email');
            $table->timestamp('user_created');
            $table->timestamp('user_modified');
            $table->timestamp('user_deleted');
            $table->timestamp('user_lastlogin');
            $table->timestamp('user_locked');

            $table->foreign('person_id')
                ->references('id')->on('persons')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Person migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('persons', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('person_id');

            $table->string('person_firstname');
            $table->string('person_surname');
        });
    }
```

Model User

```
class User extends Eloquent  {

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public function persons()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Person');
    }

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Model Person

```
class Person extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'persons';

    protected $primaryKey = 'person_id';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

I just want to change this: $user->person_id = '1'; because for every user I make the foreign key person_id is going to be 1. I want that the foreign key person_id in the users table matches the primary key person_id of the persons table.

Comment: I think need to be clear what is what you want, what is the error or the target you are follwing and doesn't get.

Comment: I'm not getting an error at all. I just want to change this: $user->person_id = '1'; because for every user I make the foreign key person_id is going to be 1. I want that the foreign key person_id in the users table matches the primary key person_id of the persons table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the query builder you may get the id of the last record inserted:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(array('email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0));
```

But if you are using Eloquent, I think you should use the associate method, this is a code sample taken from the Laravel help, you should adapt it to your user, person logic:

```
$account = Account::find(10);
$user->account()->associate($account);
$user->save()
```

Hope helps.

Comment: Now i'm using $user->person()->associate($person); and it keeps telling me SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'person_id' cannot be null

Comment: I needed to place $user->person()->associate($person, 'person_id', 'user_id'); between $person()->save; and $user()->save;